# How can we list Inventor Parameters in Forge Viewer under Model Properties?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

i uploaded a inventor model to OSS bucket , translated and viewed it to find the parameters missing. Should we follow the default translation process fo any additional tweaks?

Answer (score 0):

Model parameters are not exposed directly in the **Viewer**. But in **Inventor** you can enable parameters to be exposed through **iProperties** and those do show up in the **Viewer** as well:
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/05/inventor-iproperties-in-viewer-.html